# Question about placing several itemized lists horizontally one next to the other

Tags: positioning, itemize

This has undoubtedly been asked a zillion times but I'm am completely new at this and I've tried to google but I get directed to questions that have a similar wording to mine but whose meaning is different. I'm not even sure what are the right keywords to search for.

```
\begin{itemize}\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\item[]${Coffee}\land{\neg{Donuts}}$
\item${Cats}\land{Dogs}$
\item${You}\land{Me}$
\item${Monday}\land{Tuesday}$
\item${One,two}\land{Three}$
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\item[]${Coffee}\land{\neg{Donuts}}$
\item${Cats}\land{Dogs}$
\item${You}\land{Me}$
\item${Monday}\land{Tuesday}$
\item${One,two}\land{Three}$
\end{itemize}
```

I have several itemized lists such these ones and they all stack one on top of the other at the beginning of my page leaving the rest of the page completely empty.

What I'd like to do is to take these individual itemized lists and place one on top of the other at the left of the page, one on top of the other at right of the page so I can fill up my page.

I would be grateful for advice or links to helpful documentation.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, with the `multcol` package?

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{enumitem,amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[]$\text{Coffee} \land \neg\text{Donuts}$
    \item$\text{Cats}\land\text{Dogs}$
    \item$\text{You}\land\text{Me}$
    \item$\text{Monday}\land\text{Tuesday}$
    \item$\text{One,two}\land\text{Three}$
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item[]$\text{Coffee}\land{\neg\text{Donuts}}$
    \item$\text{Cats}\land\text{Dogs}$
    \item$\text{You}\land\text{Me}$
    \item$\text{Monday}\land\text{Tuesday}$
    \item$\text{One,two}\land\text{Three}$
  \end{itemize}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I want. Thank you very much. Just tried it and it worked great. Wanted to upvote but I need 15+ reputation